# What is etymology of "let sleeping dogs lie"?

Tags: etymology

While I know what it means, it doesn't make much sense. How can a dog lie while sleeping?

Quite curious where this came from.

Comment: @Rathony: why did you edit "sense -" to "sense;"? I'm never clear on rules about hyphen/dash/semicolon usage. Could you point me to some resources?

Comment: You can reject any edition if you don't like it. I changed it to period. I changed it because it looked like a hyphen. You can Google search it.

Comment: @Rathony: I wasn't trying to dispute the edit, I'm fine with it. Just got curious as to why, that's all.

Comment: No worry. It is always confusing and largely depends on your style and preference.

Comment: In other words, don't wake a sleeping dog, it might bite you.

Comment: Phrases cannot have an atymology,, because they have no etymon.

Comment: What do you mean "How can a dog lie while sleeping"?  They don't sleep standing up.

Comment: It's "lie" as in laying on the ground, not telling an untruth.

Comment: Why would you think a dog could tell falsehoods? This is one of those questions that raises more questions.

Comment: @StuartF  With that attitude, William Carlos Williams would have a bone to pick with you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted lie refers to sleeping. The phrase  clearly refers to  [watchdogs](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/watchdog) which have been used since ancient times  to guard people and property.  It is an old saying whose first usage instances  date back to the 18th century. Before that  the same concept was expressed with a different wording:.

> - The old saying, ***let sleeping dogs lie, means more than just to let sleeping dogs lie, which is very sound advice in the first place.  It also means that one ought not instigate trouble.  In other words, people should leave situations or people alone else it might cause them trouble.***
> - The Atlanta Constitution newspaper reported on a court case on August 6, 1909 that dealt with a Mr. Jerome who had menaced a Mr. Carvalho who had threatened Mr. Jerome.  The article read in part:
>
>   - *“You’d better let sleeping dogs lie, Mr. Jerome,” exclaimed the witness, before the district attorney had said a word. As he spoke the expert’s eyes flashed and he pointed an agitated finger at Jerome.*
> - In November of 1870, the New York Times ran an article entitled, “Russia and India: The Frontier of the Russian Empire.”  The article asked whether England was on the verge of losing its Asiatic possessions.
>
>   - *Let us consider why Russia has gained enough to suppose she is sufficiently strong to infringe the wholesome rule to “let sleeping dogs lie” when applied to the English. The Crimean War showed her plainly that her people were barbarians, and that her strength lay in brute force.*
> - ***The saying “let sleeping dogs lie” was a favourite of Sir Robert Walpole***, the first Prime Minister of Great Britain, who exercised considerable influence over King George I as well as King George II from 1721 through to 1742.  ***He was quoted as saying this on more than one occasion regardless of whether it had to do with matters of the King’s Court, the American Revolution or any other situation where difficulties had arisen.***
> - ***Geoffrey Chaucer used a similar phrase in his story, Troilus and Criseyde, published in 1374.***
>
>   - *It is nought good a sleepyng hound to wake.*
> - It’s recorded in French even earlier in the 14th century, as found in the Proverbia Vulgalia et Latina, where the saying is:  “Ne reveillez pas le chien qui dort.”  Translation: Do not wake the dog that sleeps.
> - As the phrase is referenced in the Proverbia Vulgalia et Latina, it is most likely that it comes from the Latin saying, “Quieta non movere” which means “Do not move settled things.”
>
>   - That being said, the Book of Proverbs (26:17) says:
>   - *He that passes by, and meddles with strife belonging not to him, is like one that takes a dog by the ears.*

Comment: I'm struggling not to upvote. Apparently not what OP wanted, but ELU-worthy.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - OP is asking for both, meaning and etymology. If it was only for the meaning it would be just GR.

Comment: But has accepted the answer which seems totally GR.

Comment: from https://idiomation.wordpress.com/2010/12/31/let-sleeping-dogs-lie/

Answer (score 5):

There are two meanings of the verb 'to lie'. One is to speak falsehoods, the other is to assume a horizontal position. This refers to the latter.

*Let sleeping dogs lie  ---> Let sleeping dogs continue to lie down  ---> Let sleeping dogs continue to sleep.*

If you disturb a sleeping dog it may bite you.  If you raise an issue that others have forgotten about or haven't taken much notice of then you may suffer from the  consequences.

**Example**

"I think I might  have accidentally insulted my boss last week. Should I apologize?

"Did she say anything about it or look annoyed?"

"Not really."

"In that case I would let sleeping dogs lie. She probably didn't notice. If you bring it up now you will draw her attention to it."

---

> **lie** [NO OBJECT, WITH ADVERBIAL]
>
> 1(Of a person or animal) be in or assume a horizontal or resting
>   position on a supporting surface:
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lie)

---

> **Let sleeping dogs lie**
>
> said to ​warn someone that they should not ​talk about a ​bad
>   ​situation that most ​people have ​forgotten about
>
> [Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/let-sleeping-dogs-lie)

Comment: I'm struggling not to downvote.

Comment: Which side of you will win? ;-)

Comment: I feel like failing English 101. Thanks!

Comment: Was it not about its etymology? Its  meaning is crystal clear, I guess there is a similar saying in every language.

Comment: @Josh61 - It's not necessarily crystal clear. It could conceivably mean, "Let sleeping dogs tell lies."  That appears to be what the OP thought.

Comment: OP is asking both, etymology and meaning. You cannot  make a radical change just to fit your answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Just let sleeping dogs lie.

Answer (score 0):

Geoffrey Chaucer was one of the first to put this notion into print, in Troilus and Criseyde, circa 1380 : ‘it is nought good a slepyng hound to wake’.

Comment: This is a good point, although this was already mentioned by [user66974](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/286033/191178) in an earlier answer.